# How to remove spaces from specific div span class value

Tags: jquery

How can I remove spaces from 'group2' div span class value on page load. Here is html which renders on page load. The span class value should not contain spaces (eg: "ClassicalStudies" instead of "Classical Studies"). Same follows to other span class values.

```
<div class="group2">
<p class="subject-list">
    <span class="Classical Studies">Classical Studies</span>
</p>
<p class="subject-list">
    <span class="Cognitive Science">Cognitive Science</span>
</p>
<p class="subject-list">
    <span class="Computer Engineering">Computer Engineering</span>
</p>
<p class="subject-list">
    <span class="Computer Science">Computer Science</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method with callback and replace all space in the class attribute.

```js
// attr method with callback would iterate over the 
// elements internally and you can update value by returning
$('.group2 span').attr('class', function(i, c) {
  // split by space and then join by empty string
  return c.split(' ').join('');
  // or replace all space by empty string
  // return c.replace(/\s+/g,'');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group2">
  <p class="subject-list">
    <span class="Classical Studies">Classical Studies</span>
  </p>
  <p class="subject-list">
    <span class="Cognitive Science">Cognitive Science</span>
  </p>
  <p class="subject-list">
    <span class="Computer Engineering">Computer Engineering</span>
  </p>
  <p class="subject-list">
    <span class="Computer Science">Computer Science</span>
  </p>
```

Comment: works great! Could you help me to share solution for replacing &, + along with space.

Comment: @Nikki `split(/[&\s+]+/).join('')` or  `replace(/[&\s+]+/g,'')`